# Insert selected radio button to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, radio-button, android-radiogroup

Recently done insertion of selected datepicker and edittext to the firebase database but I meet the problem when using radio button group. When I selected the radio button then the application show error and restart at the main activity again so can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Register class

```
grg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.grg);
```

//Register button click

```
grb = (RadioButton) findViewById(grg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
gender = grb.getText().toString();
```

User Class

```
   public String getGender (){
    return gender;
}

public void setGender (String gd){
    this.gender = gd;
}
```

If anyone know the solution please advice me. Thank you

Error like this
[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The app self restart again after click the register button

Comment: I understand, but there is an error in your logcat, which is?

Comment: @AlexMamo lookup the picture that i upload

Comment: This is the error that get in your emulator. Note, that a stack trace is generated whenever your app crashes because of an error or an exception. What is the error or exception?

Comment: So can you advice me where can i find this for you? ><

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html).

Comment: 08-25 15:18:57.272 1549-1581/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'bb59ca8 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: This [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) may be useful.

Comment: Oh i see. Very thank you for your helping. I will try to control the memory not to "leak"